# Which data type do I use in T-SQL if the field can be very small or very large?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, types

Suppose I have a column in a table which may hold information as short as a single char `'a'` or as big as a huge binary chunk which translates to a jpg, png, mp3, whatever.

Which data type should I use for this?

I thought `varbinary(max)` or `varchar(max)`, but will it occupy unused space if I just store a single char or a short string?

How is data stored when a field has a data-type that may have variable lengths?

According to this qa, https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1767/how-do-too-long-fields-varchar-nvarchar-impact-performance-and-disk-usage-ms, it shouldn't matter, except for this:

**Memory**

`If the client application allocates memory using the maximum size, the application would allocate significantly more memory than is necessary. Special considerations would have to be done to avoid this.`

How do I know this? Sorry if I'm being dumb but it seems too vague.

Comment: How critical is minimizing storage space?  How much do you know about your data, e.g what percentage of rows will have data less than 8 bytes long?  How many more than 1GB?  How will you know if the data is an MP3, MP4 or sonnet in Unicode?

Comment: I have a field called "data_type" which stores the information about the type. Probably no field will surpass 10MB. But most of them will store about 10~50 characters.

Comment: ASCII (8-bit) or Unicode (16-bit) characters?

Comment: Do you really have to store it in a DB? I'd rather go for storing them as binary files with unique, generated file names, while only the original name (for ref) and the generated name would go into the DB only. And the generated names could always be fixed in length.

Comment: @LaszloTenki I don't really have to store it in a DB, although that seemed easier for me at first. Are there any drawbacks to your solution?

Comment: Using external files opens all sorts of possibilities for data corruption.  A backup/restore of the database does nothing to synchronize with the files.  The files may be altered or deleted without corresponding database updates.  Users may have access to the files outside of the security provided by the database.  That said, I have done that for projects that involved indexing large quantities of legal documents.  In that case the database was serving as an index and log, but existing documents were _never_ updated.

Comment: @Conrad: small amount of additional coding to make that routine that is responsible for unique names plus the database user is not enough, you will need another user (if not impersonated) for running the code that has access to the file system folder you are storing the files in. Also, I'd keep them on a separate disk to avoid high fragmentation of the file system you have your database on. Basically that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do if I were you, is using File-Stream enable database.

You can learn more about it here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993(v=sql.105).aspx

Also there are a lot of information in the net, so you should face no issues while using it.

Generally, you will have a table with many columns as you need and one column that will store the information in binary format or BLOB - Binary Large Object. The good thing is that the information that it can store depends only by your hard disk drive space, because it is store in your drive. In the other columns you can have a type field - for eaxmaple mp3/gpef/avi/etc that will help your application to convert this BLOB in its original type.